# How to add entity reference to custom entity

Tags: 7, entities

I've created two custom entities and need to create a one to many reference between them. What I would like to achieve is to have the `Child entity` with field `Parent` that would reference the `Parent entity`. On the other hand, the `Parent entity` should have field with collection of `Children entities`.

The `Entity reference` module seems like the obvious choice, but how do I use it strictly from code to reference my custom entities in the way I described?

I also thought of just using Entity's API `Entity::setUp()` to load the references. This solutions seems simpler but what is the best *Drupalish* approach?

Both entities are fieldable.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking about "the correct way" is edgy - it can get easily closed as primarily opinion based. Now, other than that your needs are pretty clear. If you could add what have you tried? and is your entity fieldable? Can it be fieldable?

Comment: @Mołot I've changed the title :). Both entities are fieldable. I'm currently experimenting with `Entity::setUp()`, but this is very early stage of development. I'm looking for advice before I go further and make bad design decisions.

Comment: If your entities are fieldable, the simplest way would be to use [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module on them, by binding field's instance to bundles. Unfortunately I can't take enough time to actually write samples now.